# How to add multiple OR condition in required for angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I currently have this input with the required as conditional. 
I want the input to be required if isText == true or isPhone == true but it seems this is not working at all.

This is are the values I have in the typescript file

```
public isPhone= false;
public isText = false;

         <input matInput
         [(ngModel)]="model.phone"
         [required]="isText || isPhone">
```

Comment: Maybe because `byPhone` is not `isPbone` ?

Comment: Your condition should be `[required]="byText || byPhone">` OR the top variables should be `public isPhone = false;
public isText = false;`

Comment: I have created it in stackblitz `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxjnje?file=src/app/app.module.ts` but seems working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the tag form in your form with a submit button. Your bind with two variables to requried, seems to be ok!